# Masking CNAME/A Record Requirements from Clients

Tags: domain-name-system, vps, bind, dns-hosting

I'm reselling hosting services to non-technical clients.

With regards to associating domains/IPs, the host I'm reselling requires that once a VPS is deployed i then go to the domain's registrar and setup `A` and `CNAME` records that point at the VPS's IP address.

Creating `A` and `CNAME` records is not the typical "just update your name servers" and is something my clients are not comfortable with.

What should i do in order to facilitate a vanity domain that achieves the following:

- My clients can simply update their DNS records to point @ `ns*.vanitydomain.com`
- Multiple VPS (aka IPs) support

Note:

Apologies if this question is not clear -- please let me know how i can make it better.  I'm at the edge of my knowledge and because of that I've had a hard time even googling as i'm not sure what specifically i should be looking for.

Comment: Phrased differently, you want them to point the name servers for their domain to your nameservers where you can do mods yourself, provide automatisms or at least provide a more simple interface than what the most offer? Or where exactly lies your problem? I guess if they host with you it would be the logical choice to use your nameservers or use their very own running on their VPS (with secondaries outside).

Comment: @marki That sounds about right.  I'd like a client of mine to point their domain to my vanity DNS servers which then (some how) I'm able to map back to the IP my host has assigned the VPS housing the client's website.  (My client should never have to add an `A` or `CNAME` record)

Comment: Forgive my remark in case I am not understanding you completely, but is it not only your customer here who is non-technical or what is going on? They point their domain to your nameserver an you configure the nameserver such that the records point to an IP. That's daily business. Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: I'm going to be brutal here - but IMHO if you're already at the edge of your DNS knowledge here, you'll be doing your customers a disservice by trying to run their DNS for them.

Answer (score 3):

1. Start by using proper terminology. I don't care what anybody else says or thinks but there is no such thing as a vanity domain or a vanity name server. There are domains and there are name servers. You may choose to call them "vanity" as a cheeky marketing ploy but you're only serving to confuse your customers more by calling them something that has no root in technical accuracy.
2. It doesn't sound like you have the requisite technical knowledge to be managing the name servers for your customers so I would advise you no to.
3. I work for a client that hosts email for a large number of customers. This client does not host the DNS for these customers. This client advises their customers on what DNS records to create/change and assists them in doing so if needed. If you are not in the business of providing rock solid, fault tolerant DNS then you shouldn't be doing so.
4. I see this all of the time. Someone hosts a VPS, or a web site, or email for a domain and they think they should/need to host the DNS for the domain. They don't have the technical know-how or the appropriate infrastructure for doing so and the next thing you know, a customer's public presence (email, web, etc.) is unavailable because something's wrong with their DNS, because someone who has no business hosting DNS is hosting it and has fouled it up.

Comment: Would using a 3rd party DNS provider allow me to have a client point @ my DNS servers -- which then point them back @ the host i resell for?

Comment: Why not just have the client create the appropriate A or CNAME record for the VPS at their current DNS host? Why do you want them to use your DNS servers? You're hosting a VPS for them, you don't need to host their DNS to do that.

Comment: Joe if you have a solution to the question i asked i'd love to hear it. Otherwise please stop responding -- your initial answer and follow up to my comment do not work towards a resolution

Comment: You posted a comment/question to my answer so I responded to it. If you don't want people to respond to you then don't post follow up questions to their answers. The solution is to leave the customer DNS as it is with whatever entity is currently hosting their DNS. You provide assistance to them in creating the appropriate DNS records in their existing DNS zone at their existing name servers for your VPS. Simple. I do it all of the time with our email customers. We assist them in setting up the appropriate MX, SPF and TXT records at their existing DNS host.

Comment: @user3290740 IMHO, Joe's response is right on the money.

Comment: Kind of old, but... wow!  Guy get's ripped apart for asking a question?  And the answer is... that he is basically too dumb so just give it up, don't bother?  How did any of these folks get to know anything then?  Obviously not by taking their own advice.  Why not actually answer the question?  The proposed 'answer' doesn't even address the question.  I was looking for something useful.  Why waste people's time with this?  If you can't, or won't, answer the question, don't post your response like it is one.

Comment: @jdmayfield You're absolutely right. My "answer" wasn't really an answer. I let my personal frustration of dealing with this very issue color my response. It was counter productive and probably mean-spirited (although that wasn't me intention).

Comment: @joequerty Nice!  Gotta give you some serious cred for that response, though.  Everyone has their day, both good and bad.  Thinking about it helped me find the answer though.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To use existing name-servers (i.e. your registrar's) under your own host-names:

1. Get IP's of name-servers you want to use.

   Ex:  ping ns1.myregistrar.com  --> 1.2.3.4

   Ex:  ping ns2.myregistrar.com  --> 4.3.2.1
2. Add each IP as a 'Glue Record'.

   Ex:  1.2.3.4 --> ns1.mydomain.com

   Ex:  4.3.2.1 --> ns2.mydomain.com

(How depends on your provider.)

3. Update domain's name-servers.

   Ex:  ns1.myregistrar.com --> ns1.mydomain.com

   Ex:  ns2.myregistrar.com --> ns2.mydomain.com

That's it.  Now your nameservers will show in 'whois' as ns1.mydomain.com, etc.  Other than that, all will be the same as before (i.e. however you managed the DNS records, for instance).

Poof!  You now have branded name-servers, without even hosting them.

Note:  You don't need CNAMEs or anything else, just the Glue Records!

Comment: Update:  This has worked perfectly so far on my own server... so far, no issues.  All DNS running perfectly smooth on custom-named name-servers since putting in the glue records with the registrar's IP's.

Comment: As a side note, I set the A record for ns1.* and ns2.* to my servers IP, which means pings will resolve to my server's address, not the name-servers IP's in the glue records.   So if you ping ns1.* you get the servers IP, but the DNS system references the IP's in the Glue records.

Comment: Update:  Just wanted to mention, the glue record method is still working perfectly for my domains.  Additional note:  Without an A record you won't get back a ping, but you can set any IP for an A record to the sub/domain you use for the glue records, get back a ping, and use it for any other purposes, separately.  They don't interfere with each other.  So unless they dig for the glue records, or some equivalent measure, the curious will only see the IP you assigned in the A record.  I have access to many different devices in my work, so this has been broadly tested.